# Changing the password used to protect an EFS encryption key

Tags: encryption, efs

I have various folders encrypted using Windows EFS encryption.  I'd like to change the password which protects the EFS key in question (the password that is required when importing the certificate and key to a new machine).

If possible, I'd prefer to change the password of the existing, installed key rather than stop encrypting those folders, delete the key, and create another. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [You will have to create a new certificate to accomplish your goal.](https://superuser.com/questions/484726/windows-8-efs-how-to-tell-windows-to-use-this-certificate-for-efs-encryption?rq=1).  You don't have to stop encrypting the files.

Comment: @Ramhound... Duplicate, right?

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT - I would think it's a duplicate, I wasn't sure, so figured somebody else can raise the flag.